# Customize Listview item based on object data

Tags: android, xml, listview, parse-platform, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to change the look of a single element in a Listview based on the object's properties, in this case background color and textcolor.

The object represents a tram with a background color, text color, number of the tram.

I was thinking something like this

[image]

The usage is a AutoCompleteTextView where a user can input a number, and the application will then list all possible matches.

I'm using parse for storing the data objects in a database and the storage/retrieving aspect is not a problem.

I can do it, very ugly, with

```
 TextView line = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.transportline);


        if(ctrlListItems.get(position).getLine().equals("1")){
            line.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
```

But I rather want to use the XML files like

```
line.setBackground(drawable/line_white);
```

where

line_white

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<!-- view background color -->
<solid
    android:color="@color/tram_white_bg" >
</solid>

<!-- view border color and width -->
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/tram_border_gray" >
</stroke>

<!-- The radius makes the corners rounded -->
<corners
    android:radius="2dp"   >
</corners>
```

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Hi!

Try with line.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line_white);

Answer (score 0):

I decided to port the color information for text/background color to the parse Data object since I most likely will be porting the application to iOS at some later point anyway. They are stored as Strings in the Parse database as "#ffffff"

I'm using a Shape Drawable as the standard layout for the number.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<!-- view background color -->
<solid
    android:color="@color/tram_white_bg" >
</solid>

<!-- view border color and width -->
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/tram_border_gray" >
</stroke>

<!-- The radius makes the corners rounded -->
<corners
    android:radius="2dp"   >
</corners>
```

and in my custom ArrayAdapter I can avoid alot of if/case to determine color which makes the application easier to scale with more objects added.

```
GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable)holder.lineNumber.getBackground();
    shape.setColor(Color.parseColor(line.getBgColor()));
    holder.lineNumber.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(line.getTextColor()));
```

Yields this result

[image: this]